# has-feedback error is not working on bootstrap table on form validation in laravel

Tags: forms, laravel-5

**We do generally error validation for the div tags as below**

```
 <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('Email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}" id="">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label "> Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" >
                  @if ($errors->has('Email')) 
                  <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  {{ $errors->first('Email') }}</p>
                    @endif
                </div>
              </div>
```

Here is my table code :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped-col nomargin" id="table-data">
                    <tr align="center">
                      <td>Event Name</td>
                      <td>Event Code</td>
                      <td>Event Date</td>
                      <td>City</td>
                      <td>Country</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>

                      <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('eventname') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="eventname[]" >
                        @if ($errors->has('eventname')) 
                  <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  {{ $errors->first('eventname') }}</p>
                    @endif
                    </div>

                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="eventcode[]" >
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control dob"  autocomplete="off" name="date[]" >
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="city[]" >
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="country[]" >
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="button" value="+" class="add btn btn-success">
                        <input type="button" value="-" class="delete btn btn-danger">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

[image]

**the same i m using on the table for array inputs as well but its not working**

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('eventname') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
     <input type="text" class="form-control " autocomplete="off" name="eventname[]" >
      @if ($errors->has('eventname')) 
       <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      {{ $errors->first('eventname') }}</p>
      @endif
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**I have tried a ways but it is not working ..Please suggest me how to use this validation on bootstrap table ?**

Answer (score 0):

Just in your `<td>` tag add the div with `form-group` class, something like the below.

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td>
       <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}" id="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " autocomplete="off" name="email" >
        @if ($errors->has('email')) 
           <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      {{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
        @endif
       </div>
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In order to display errors for input array you need to the following:

```
<table>
<tr>
     @if(null !== old('email'))
           @for($i=0;$i<count(old('email'));$i++)
              <td>
                 <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('email'.$i) ? 'has-error' : '' }}" id="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " autocomplete="off" name="email[]" value="{{old('email'.$i)}}">
                    @if ($errors->has('email'.$i)) 
                        <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        {{ $errors->first('email'.$i) }}</p>
                    @endif
                </div>
             </td>
          @endfor
      @else 
          <td>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}" id="">
                <input type="text" class="form-control " autocomplete="off" name="email" >
            @if ($errors->has('email')) 
               <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          {{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
            @endif
           </div>
          </td>
     @endif

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah your answer is correct .but how do we give the same for array inputs ?

Comment: where is the array in your code? how do you place it inside your table?

Comment: i have edited my question .can you see the name of input email[] in table

Comment: I have used a similar code in one of my application, it works. If it's not working for you, then it needs some adjustment for variable names. Did you try to debug and know why it's not working?

Comment: I have adjusted some variable names, please check now.

Comment: i was trying by adjusting variable names itself but it is still not working .And in the request format i was using for loop for the validation like as below :       ` foreach($this->request->get('email') as $key => $val)
                      {
                        $rules['email.'.$key] = 'required';
                      }`
the error it says like **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: OK, actually now we are deviating from the original question into validation rules. You can ask another question to get feedback on validation. For the Form and CSS part, the provided code should work.